# How can I realize infinite scroll in ListView using AsyncTask and callback interface?

Tags: java, android, listview, scroll, android-asynctask

I don't know how to realize infinite scroll in ListView. I just want to add the next 25 issues to the mListAllIssues view every time I get the bottom of it.

**AllIssuesFragment.java:**

```
public class AllIssuesFragment extends Fragment {

@Bind(R.id.list_all_issues) ListView mListAllIssues;
public static boolean loading;
IssuesGetter mi;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences user_data = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("user_data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    UserManager.getInstance().setUsername(user_data.getString("username", null));
    UserManager.getInstance().setPassword(user_data.getString("password", null));

    if(UserManager.getInstance().getUsername() == null || UserManager.getInstance().getPassword() == null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.activity, ChangeUserActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else {
        mi = new IssuesGetter(new AsyncCallback<IssuesResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IssuesResponse response) {
                ArrayAdapter<IssuesResponse.Issue> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<IssuesResponse.Issue>(MainActivity.activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, response.getIssues());
                mListAllIssues.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.activity, ChangeUserActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        mi.execute(Constants.URI + Constants.ISSUES + Constants.OFFSET + 0);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_issues, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}
}
```

**AsyncCallback.java:**

```
public interface AsyncCallback<T> {
    void onSuccess(T response);
    void onError();
}
```

**IssuesGetter.java:**

public class IssuesGetter extends AsyncTask {

```
private final AsyncCallback<IssuesResponse> callback;

public IssuesGetter(AsyncCallback<IssuesResponse> callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    HttpURLConnection c = null;
    try {
        c = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(strings[0]).openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    c.setUseCaches(false);
    try {
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    c.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    c.setRequestProperty("Authorization", UserManager.getInstance().getUserPass());
    int responseCode = 0;
    try {
        responseCode = c.getResponseCode();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(responseCode == 200) {
        try {
            c.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((c.getInputStream())));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String output;
        try {
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(output);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(result == null) {
        callback.onError();
    }
    else {
        IssuesResponse issues = new Gson().fromJson(result, IssuesResponse.class);
        callback.onSuccess(issues);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?  And don't say "How do I do it", that's too broad of a question.  You should try something first, and then ask if you get stuck.  Here's a hint: `OnScrollListener `.

Comment: Yep, I've tried it. But the problem is that it is impossible to execute the same  asynctask several times.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting data from the web Api right ? If yes your problem can be easily solved . Just modify you web api to accept 2 parameters like offset and next n records. It helps to reduce the api calls like you can put time constraints like when data loads you can take currentMillis() and check for another Millis and according to your time you can block calls to your api. You can implement that very easily.
Here is example of [endless scrolling](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews)

Answer (score 1):

You should use your Adapter that provides the items for the ListView to make this happen.

1. Instead of returning X as the count, return X + 1
2. When retrieving X + 1 Item from the Adapter, you return a View that has the loading animation and also perform your AsyncTask operation to retrieve the next set of items from your list view. Your callback should be within the Adapter itself.
3. When your AsyncTask operation completed, you insert the new data into your internal data structure within your Adapter.
4. Call notifyItemRangeChanged or notifyDataSetChanged as needed.